# How to create topic in Kafka that running like task in AWS ECS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-kafka, amazon-ecs

How to create a topic in Kafka that runs like a task in the AWS ECS cluster? I think about AWS CLI, but I don't know what URL I need to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an AdminClient interface (if you have admin creds).
For example you can use python `confluent_kafka` package or any other lib.

```
from confluent_kafka.admin import AdminClient, NewTopic


admin_client = AdminClient({
    "bootstrap.servers": "cluster_in_ecs:9092"
})

topic_list = []
topic_list.append(NewTopic("new_topic", 3, 2))
admin_client.create_topics(topic_list)
```